# Samsung Galaxy2 , Android , webpage unavailable 192.168.1.xx

Tags: android, localhost, galaxy

I am testing local website on several mobile devices and on ipad , iphone nokia etc ,
wamp is setup to let anyone on the network in

I can see my website via 192.168.1.101/folder

but not on Galaxy ,  I checked and made sure that I am connected via Wi-fi to my localhost.

tried 10.0.2.2/folder

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked firewall as well for forwarded ports?

Comment: The galaxy is coming from outside the network on 3G or inside via Wifi?